# Having difficulty running a SQL Script in Visual Studio 2012 due to removal of Data menu and inability to find Transact-SQL Editor.

Tags: t-sql, visual-studio-2012

I'm working through a WCF project, and I'm trying to create a persistence store for the service.  Unfortunately, the walkthrough I'm following describes how to do this in Visual Studio 2010, and the Data menu is no longer available in 2012.  I've created the database for the service to use, but I need to execute the SqlPersistenceProviderSchema.sql script on it and I'm stumped as to how I would do that.  In Visual Studio 2010, I would click Data > Transact-SQL Editor, connect to the created database, and then execute the SQL script.  How would this be accomplished in VS2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably several ways, but this gets you used to a new window (Server Explorer) that I find useful for multiple things.

View -> Server Explorer

Data Connections -> (right click) Add Connection

Data source: Microsoft SQL Server

Standard connection window appears -> enter your connection info and connect

(right click) your new connection under Data Connections -> New Query

It depends on your SQL Server Data Tools install at some point so you might have to download and install it.

Comment: I've tried running it as a query, but I get syntax errors...the script I'm trying to run is C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\SQL\en\SqlPersistenceProviderSchema.sql

Comment: I followed these steps in Visual Studio 2013 and it ran fine, and created the tables. My Visual Studio 2012 wants to update my Data Tools to be able to follow these steps in it, which I don't want to do right now. I don't know of any reason why you would have syntax errors.

Comment: It turns out my SQL Server Data Tools install didn't work.  Once I reinstalled everything I was able to successfully run the script using the Run Query command as described by shriop.  For those looking for the missing Transact-SQL Editor menu item, it will be available under the SQL menu item once the Data Tools successfully install.